# How to remove a Button View from CardView before generating a bitmap from the CardView?

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I have a CardView in the Android Application which can be shared as a bitmap. How can I remove a Button View from that CardView before generating the bitmap? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you generating the bitmap. The easiest way is to hide the button by

```
setVisibility(GONE);
```

before generating the bitmap.